# Databricks spark configuration using secrets in property name

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is it possible to refer to a databricks secret in my property name like this:

```
fs.azure.account.auth.type.{{secrets/my_scope/my_secret1}}.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
fs.azure.account.auth.type.{{secrets/my_scope/my_secret2}}.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
```

or is secrets only allowed for the assigned value?

My databricks workflows fails with the current message
Failure to initialize configuration for storage account [REDACTED].dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

I am not 100% certain it is a problem with the configuration, so I just want to make sure it is possible before looking for other issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible - secrets are matched by the full value, not substituted inside the string - it's described in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/secrets.html#syntax-for-referencing-secrets-in-a-spark-configuration-property-or-environment-variable).  It's also easy to check. For example, if you start a cluster with such value, and then use Scala snippet to filter out necessary values:

```
%scala

spark.conf.getAll.filter { _._1.contains(".dfs.core.windows.net")}
```

then you should get something like this:

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(
  fs.azure.account.auth.type.{{secrets/my_scope/my_secret1}}.dfs.core.windows.net -> OAuth
)
```

showing that no substitution happened. The error message is a bit misleading because it's detected that you refers the secret and redacted it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better to ask this question on the [Databricks community forum](https://community.databricks.com), as it is very product specific and not a general programming question. Also I'd recommend reading the documentation on [secret redaction](https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/redaction.html). I think the substituion is possible like that, since it showing as [REDACTED] in the printed notebook output is an indication that it was inserted correctly.